# Gatsby language localization (language change using one button)

Tags: reactjs, localization, gatsby

I have this code which enables the language switch between English and German using two separate buttons (anchor tags).
The problem is I have to enable this switch using only one button, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Here is the "language.js" component:

```
import { IntlContextConsumer, changeLocale } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"

const languageName = {
  en: "English",
  de: "Deutsch",
}

const Language = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <IntlContextConsumer>
        {({ languages, language: currentLocale }) =>
          languages.map(language => (
            <a
              key={language}
              onClick={() => changeLocale(language)}
              style={{
                color: currentLocale === language ? `yellow` : `white`,
                margin: 10,
                textDecoration: `underline`,
                cursor: `pointer`,
              }}
            >
              {languageName[language]}
            </a>
          ))
        }
      </IntlContextConsumer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Language
```

If you need any other component please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your response. :)

ps. 
Localization is done without a i18 implementation.

Comment: Are you looking to create a language picker? A minimal workable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot, as well as an illustration of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, not a language picker.

The main idea is: 
1)  default language is English
2) there is a button with "DE" text on it
3) when clicked, the website should be translated to German and the button's text should be changed to "EN".   

Following demo operates with three buttons (anchor tags):
https://gatsby-starter-default-intl.netlify.com/en/

Here's the source:
https://github.com/wiziple/gatsby-plugin-intl/tree/master/examples/gatsby-starter-default-intl

The problem is I want only one button to handle the translation (English - German, without Korean).

Comment: In that case what prevents you from using a single button with text dependant on the other available locale?

Answer (score 1):

Following simple example should yield the expected result when only using two languages like in your snippet. If you add languages to your configuration then it will always display all languages **except** the current locale.

```
import React from "react"
import { IntlContextConsumer, changeLocale } from "gatsby-plugin-intl"

const languageName = {
  en: "EN",
  de: "DE",
}

const LanguageToggle = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <IntlContextConsumer>
        {({ languages, language: currentLocale }) =>
          languages.map(language => {
            if (language != currentLocale) {
              return (
                <a key={language} onClick={() => changeLocale(language)}>
                  {languageName[language]}
                </a>
              )
            }
          })
        }
      </IntlContextConsumer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LanguageToggle
```